# What can be included in an OSGI Library

Tags: osgi, xpages

Can an OSGI library include Forms and views or is it restricted to just the XPages elements?

Answer (score 2):

An XSP Library (one type of OSGi plugin that is directly applicable to XPages -- DOTS is another instance of this type) can contribute any artifact type that is defined in the [XPages configuration file format](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_configuration_file_format) (a.k.a. "xsp-config"). [This wiki article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_and_Implementing_Complex_Types) is a good overview of creating these kinds of artifacts. I also recommend looking at the source code of the [XSP Starter Kit](http://www.openntf.org/p/XSP%20Starter%20Kit) project on OpenNTF, as it contains reference implementations of many different types of XSP artifacts, including several that aren't listed in the above wiki references.

Since the XPages architecture was largely inspired by [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), the vast majority of the types of artifacts you can distribute in this manner are not inherently associated with Domino -- rather, you're defining concrete implementations of the same concepts used by developers working with other JSF implementations (e.g. [JBoss RichFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RichFaces), [Apache MyFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_MyFaces)). As such, an XSP Library is *not* designed for distribution of design elements traditionally associated with the Lotus Notes client, such as Forms / Subforms / Views, etc. (traditional design elements that should behave consistently across multiple applications should continue to be distributed using Domino's design element inheritance features).

Well-designed XSP Library artifacts are, therefore, [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) in this regard: like some of the data sources that ship with the platform, which are designed to be passed properties like `formName` or `viewName` in order to define each instance's relationship to the back-end data model, but make no assumptions about the contents or design thereof, each custom XSP Library artifact should be designed to perform a specific function independently of anything else the library (or application) might contain, and support a set of properties sufficient to instruct it *how* to perform that function differently than another instance of the same artifact might.

Comment: If I have a custom contro/XPage that uses a JS Library as a resource I could not see a way of making that part of an OSGI. Also, some of the cc's and xp's reference elements from the Extension Library and when I add the custom control to the OSGI it shows a bunch of errors. Would those errors be resolved when the OSGI is installed into a system that has the Extension Library also installed?

Comment: Have you checked out the XSP Starter Kit as I suggested? It includes a reference implementation of bundling JS libraries. I believe it also demonstrates specifying a dependency on another library, such as IBM's Extension Library.

Comment: I have looked at the Starter Kit, but obviously need to spend some more time in it. Thanks.